# Google spreadsheet not opening through google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to open google spreadsheet through website url.

I am getting the following message that.

The document is inaccessible. Please try again later.

It was working fine till now, all of a sudden it started showing above error message.

I am attaching the error screenshot with this thread.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wD275.png)

Comment: If I well undersatnd you can't open the spreadsheet from its url ? Do you check if it is not an error on your network ? Can you try to open the url with your smartphone for example ?

Comment: Our Internet is working fine, tested on other person desktop in chicago.

Comment: Are you able to access the spreadsheet by using it's URL? If so, create a [mcve] and add the code to the question.